# How to calculate expected value for a bid contract?

Tags: probability, expected-value

A company plans to open a bid of \$3000 per tonne for a contract to supply 1000 tonnes of metal. Assume that 2 competitors A and B will place bids. The probability that A places a bid less than 3000$ per tonne is 0.3 and probability that B places a bid less than \$3000 per tonne is 0.7. If the lowest bidder wins the contract, what is the Expected Value of the contract when it is assumed that the each competitor will bid independently.

I have no idea to do this problem. All I know is that if there's a specific \$ value for a known probability then I can get the expected value of it using the product of it. But in this question no such value is given but only a range. So your help is much needed. Thank you very much!

Also if anyone can provide with related tags you are most welcome.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  What does it mean for a company to "open a bid of $\$3000$ per ton"?  I thought there was to be an auction, no?  And, more importantly, knowing that $A$ has a $.3$ chance of bidding below $\$3000$ doesn't tell us much about the probability distribution of $A's$ bid.

Comment: I think that the company wants to find a suplier for 1000 tonnes of metal. So company is trying to get supplier for \$3000 per tonne

Comment: Well...what does the $3000$ signify, then?  Suppose $A$ offers at $3100$ and $B$ offers at $3250$.  Does the company refuse to buy because both offers exceed their level?

Comment: I don't think the question can be answered without more information, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the $3000$ number means that if both $A$ and $B$ bid more than that no contract will be let and the value is $0$.  Otherwise, the value of the contract is the difference between $3000$ and the low bid.  You are asked for the expected value of the contract which you cannot find without knowing the probability distribution of $A$'s and $B$'s bids.

I can make up a probability distribution consistent with the data.  Say $A$ bids $2850$ with probability $0.3$ and $B$ bids $2900$ with probability $0.7$.  Otherwise, each bids some number greater than $3000$.  If $A$ bids $2850$ it will win the job and the contract has a value of $150$.  If $B$ wins the job (which only happens if $A$ bids high and $B$ bids low) the value of the contract is $100$.  The expected value of the contract is then
$$0.3 \cdot 150 + (1-0.3)\cdot 0.7 \cdot 100=94$$
If you have overlapping probability distributions you will need to integrate over the regions that each company wins the bid.